# Confidence intervals on model parameters

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

I have a very basic question about interpreting confidence intervals. Say I use R to fit a linear model to the Nile water flow time series (from the `datasets` package), like this:

```
# Flow of the Nile river (10^8 cubic metres per year) between 1871-1971
nile.ts <- data.frame(year = do.call(seq, as.list(attributes(Nile)$tsp)),
           flow = as.numeric(Nile))

# Fit linear function 
nile.fit <- gls(flow ~ year, data = nile.ts)
```

Next, I look at the confidence intervals on the model parameters:

```
# Look at 95% confidence intervals
intervals(nile.fit)
```

> ```
> Approximate 95% confidence intervals
>
>  Coefficients:
>                   lower        est.       upper
> (Intercept) 4144.217893 6132.173579 8120.129266
> year          -3.749313   -2.714305   -1.679298
> attr(,"label")
> [1] "Coefficients:"
>
>  Residual standard error:
>    lower     est.    upper 
> 132.1041 150.5522 175.0363
> ```

Here, the coefficient of year in the model is estimated to be $-2.7$ and has a 95% confidence interval of $[-3.7, -1.7]$. I'd read this as meaning I can be pretty confident that there has been a decline in the flow over time. But what if the confidence interval had been $[-3.7, +1.7]$? Since it straddles zero, does this mean that I can't say anything about the trend? Or, can I state that there is no statistically significant trend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or, can I state that there is no statistically significant trend?

Yes. The coefficient for `year` would be then not different from 0.

Comment: @ Lyngbakr, you can use a more formal wording that is based on the **p-value** in the model output, which is that: the probability that a coefficient estimate will be at least as large as the observed value when the Null hypothesis is true.